# Complexity of scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage

Tags: performance, scipy, time-complexity, space-complexity

What are the time and space complexities of the function `linkage' of the scipy module`scipy.cluster.hierarchy`?

I tried looking at the [release notes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html), but didn't find any help there. Based on the description of the algorithm in the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage), I can assume the time complexity is O(N), but I need to be sure.

Is there any easy way to find out the time and space complexities of `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage`, or do I have to go through the source code?